# Is there an app that allows an iPhone-to-iPhone local network call with shared music?

Tags: iphone, network, music, call

My wife and I started going to a gym recently.  We each have our own separate workouts and we listen to music through our earbuds.  We realized though that this has reduced our evening chat time, so I had this idea to "call" each other to idly (verbally) chat during our separate workouts at the gym.  And I was wondering if it was possible for us to listen to the same music as we chat.  I've tried a bunch of different searches, but the best I can figure is that we can make an actual phone call and listen to our own separate music.  We have unlimited plans, so that's a possibility, but I think it would really be nice if we were listening to the same music (with independent volume control, i.e. voice versus music).  Is there an app that will do this, ideally just over a local network (as opposed to making a call that routes through a cell phone tower or some internet service)?

Comment: i'm not aware of any apps that do both shared music and talking.  However, if I were you, I'd tell her there isn't any app like that and then enjoy your blissfully quite time alone at the gym :-).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no. I found a [link](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/19/listen-to-music-while-on-phone-calls-iphone/) to an article that explains this.

> Playing music or any other audio while on a phone call is easy:
>
> While on an active phone call, tap the Home button to get to the home
>   screen Open the Music app, find any song or podcast, and press play
>   Return to the phone call screen by tapping the green titlebar Music
>   (or any audio) plays immediately, but **instead of outputting through
>   the external speakers, it will be played through the ear speaker**. *This
>   prevents the music from being piped through to the other end of the
>   phone*, and that means the other end will never know you’re jamming to
>   Milli Vanilli to make it through their tortuously boring phone calls
>   and wait times.